# Batch script terminates in case of error when using pipe operator

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, pipe

I need to perferm error handling (check ERRORLEVEL) on an operation involving the pipe operator, but instead of the script continuing with a non-zero ERRORLEVEL, it terminates immediately. How can I avoid this behavior?

Consider the following example. (Note that is a simplified constructed example to illustrate the problem - not a meaningful script)

```
someinvalidcommand
echo nextline
```

This will result in

```
> 'someinvalidcommand' is not recognized as ... command...
> nextline
```

In other words, the script continues after the error.
Now consider

```
echo firstline | someinvalidcommand
echo nextline
```

This will result in only

```
> 'someinvalidcommand' is not recognized as ... command ...
```

That is, it terminates before evaluating "echo nextline"

Why this behavior and how to avoid it ? The purpose is to perform something similar to

```
someoperation | someotheroperation
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    handleerror
)
```

but the error handling has no effect since it stops early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate it to another `cmd` instance

```dos
cmd /c" someoperation | someotheroperation "
if errorlevel 1 (
    handleerror
)
```